# Float to int in C unexpected output

Tags: c

I have the following code in C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    float a = 1.88;
    a =a - (0.25 * 7 + 0.1 * 1);
    a = a *100;
    printf("a = %f\n",a );
    int b =(int) (a);
    printf("b = %d\n", b);
}
```

The value of b should be `2` but I get the following output-

```
a = 3.000000
b = 2
```

Why is it so?

Comment: It took me 10 seconds to read the first google hit for "C convert float to int": http://c-faq.com/fp/round.html. Your code is truncating, not converting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: I suspect you mean "b should be 3 but why it is 2"? Answer is given below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you change

```
printf("a = %f\n",a );
```

to

```
printf("a = %.20f\n",a );
```

it outputs

```
a = 2.99999952316284179688
```

As you can see this is not 3.

So the conversion truncates it to 2.

Answer (score 0):

When a float is converted to int only the integer part is stored i.e 2.9 only 2 is stored and remaining is truncated. 
Similar one in the case of division

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int a=12/5;
    printf("%d\n",a);
}
```

Here the result is 2.4 but .4 is truncated ..